# What should Java's main() method and its containing class be doing?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm pretty new to programming, but in C I would have had a main function that called all the other methods needed to run the program. In Java, though, I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732151/java-main-method-good-coding-style) - which suggests putting the main() method in a class of its own, with that class' responsibility only being to initialise the program. Should I have another class (say, a 'system' class) that only calls methods (i.e. runs the program?). And if so, is there any convention for naming the main class?

Comment: Your link is *Page Not Found*

Comment: the main method in java does the same as in C, it provides an entry point for VM to start execution (i don't imply that C's main has something to do with the JM).

Comment: Ok, thanks! So is it ok to call a bunch of methods? Or was I misunderstanding its purpose in C?

Comment: What do you want your application to be called?  The "main" must be in the class that is named on the `java` command when the app is invoked.  Generally you would have at most one instance of that class (if it weren't entirely static methods), with other classes for your "real" logic.  There's no hard-and-fast rule, just what makes sense given the restrictions that are inherent in creating a class.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to have a bunch of methods there.  And often the main class will have some instance fields, and an instance of the class serves as the "data anchor" for the application.

Comment: True,thanks. I forgot about using the 'main' name with the java command.

Comment: Yes, if you want to make a class runable you have to have a main method inside it so can execute it this way `java MainClass`. From that entry point you can do what ever you want inside that method or that same class or other classes (other classes have be in the classpath). You can name it whatever you want it just have to have main method in it. Just like you would name an `.exe` file whatever you want.

Comment: In the page you linked the significant point is that the class is a `Runnable`, meaning that (possibly multiple) instances of it will be created for running as separate threads, et al.  As such, combining with the application's "main" class is a poor idea.

Comment: `runable` in my last comment is not the same as in the question you've linked, see @HotLicks comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main method is similar to the main function in C and C++; it's the
>   entry point for your application and will subsequently invoke all the
>   other methods required by your program.

The method signature

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Any class could contain a `main` method but the only one

Calling a class `main` method

```
java MyApp arg1 arg2
```

where MyApp is a class contains a `main` method.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, much appreciated.

Comment: I should probably post a new question, but is it ok to only have one (long-ish) method in your main class?